# If TableView has no results show "no results" label (2 counts)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, count

Im trying to complete my search feature and this is the only thing i have left missing.Basically what i want is when my `searchTableView` doesn't have any results a label will show up and say "no results" just like **WhatsApp** :

[image]

I know how to set up the label and make it show up correctly if there are no results with one `count` needed, but i don't know how to set the label to `isHidden` correctly when there are no results with 2 `counts` that needs to be equal to `0`.

## let me explain :

**numberOfRowsInSection:**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        
        if tableView == self.tableView {
            
        return self.names.count
            
        } else {
            return self.filteredUsers.count
        }
        
    }
```

I need Both `self.names.count` & `self.filteredUsers.count` to be equal to 0 and than i will write `isHidden = false`

**Label i Have:**

```
BarsSearchNoResultsLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 60, y: 70, width: 200, height: 50))
        BarsSearchNoResultsLabel.textAlignment = .center
        BarsSearchNoResultsLabel.text = "אין תוצאות"
        BarsSearchNoResultsLabel.font = UIFont(name:"HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 25.0)
        BarsSearchNoResultsLabel.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
        self.view.addSubview(BarsSearchNoResultsLabel)
```

So how do i make this code to count both `filteredUseres` & `names` ?:

```
        if self.names.count == 0
    //Needs to count self.filteredUsers.count == 0 as well ! 
    {
                    self.BarsSearchNoResultsLabel.isHidden = false
                    return 0
                } else {
                    self.BarsSearchNoResultsLabel.isHidden = true
                    return self.names.count;
//Needs to return both names & filteredUsers!
                }
            }
```

It will be really great if you could help me .

Thanks for your help !

## What i tried :

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        
        guard self.names.count !=0 && self.filteredUsers.count != 0 else {
            self.BarsSearchNoResultsLabel.isHidden = false
            return 0
        }
        
        self.BarsSearchNoResultsLabel.isHidden = true
        if tableView == self.tableView {
            return self.names.count
        } else {
            return self.filteredUsers.count
        }
    }
```

[image]

Im getting a lot of errors.

Comment: Just add the `&& self.filteredUsers.count == 0` to your if statement

Comment: As a side note, assuming `BarsSearchNoResultsLabel ` is not a class but an instance, it should start with a lowercase `barsSearchNoResultsLabel `.

Comment: Does it matter ? @bauerMusic

Comment: @NewbieQuestions To the compiler? Absolutely not, but we (humans) want to be able to understand what you meant ;)

Comment: @Paulw11 How do i handle the `return`s my app crashes. see "**What i tried**" in the question

Comment: You shouldn't perform this check in `numberOfRowsInSection` - you should perform the check where you update the arrays

Comment: i did the same on another searchController with 1 count and it works perfectly is it not possible with 2 counts? @Paulw11

Comment: It's possible, it's just not the right place to do it.

Comment: can you help me with code please? i really want it to work @Paulw11

Comment: use this lib : https://github.com/dzenbot/DZNEmptyDataSet easy to use

Answer (score 0):

According to me it would be better to add backgroundView to tableView.

after reload method:

```
tableview.reloadData()
```

write:

```
if results.count == 0{
tableview.backroundView = noDataLabel
}
```

while searching /fetching data:

```
tableview.backroundView = nil
```

Comment: i would prefer my way if may i say...i would prefer if you could help me make what i tried work

Answer (score 0):

Try like this!

Take one UILable from Story board and put into UIview[image]

Now use like this!

```
@IBOutlet weak var Notfound: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
@IBOutlet weak var SearchTableView: UITableView!

var searchActive : Bool = false
var data = ["San Francisco","New York","San Jose","Chicago","Los Angeles","Austin","Seattle"]
var filtered:[String] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    /* Setup delegates */
    SearchTableView.delegate = self
    SearchTableView.dataSource = self
    searchBar.delegate = self
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}

func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchActive = true;
}

func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchActive = false;
}

func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchActive = false;
}

func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchActive = false;
}

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

    if searchText != ""{

        filtered = data.filter({ (text) -> Bool in
            let tmp: NSString = text as NSString
            let range = tmp.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive)
            return range.location != NSNotFound
        })
        if(filtered.count == 0){
            searchActive = false;
            Notfound.isHidden = false
            SearchTableView.isHidden = true
        } else {
            searchActive = true;
            Notfound.isHidden = true
            SearchTableView.isHidden = false
        }
        SearchTableView.reloadData()
    }else{

        filtered = data
        SearchTableView.isHidden = false
        SearchTableView.reloadData()
    }

}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if(searchActive) {
        return filtered.count
    }
    return data.count;
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")! as UITableViewCell;
    if(searchActive){
        cell.textLabel?.text = filtered[indexPath.row]
    } else {
        cell.textLabel?.text = data[indexPath.row];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: I just give the way of how to search the text and it's working fine Just try to test it

Comment: ok i will try it now.Can you maybe in the meanwhile try to make what i tried work? I'm curious to see if it can be worked out.

Answer (score 0):

From a architectural point of view, I would suggest that you show/hide the label where you update your data source arrays; This way you only execute the code and show/hide the label when you know the data has changed.  The code is also executed as a direct result of updating the data rather than as a side-effect of reloading the tableview.

However, if you want to do it in `numberOfRowsInSection` you can use something like this:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        let namesCount = self.names?.count ?? 0
        let filteredCount = self.filteredUsers?.count ?? 0
        guard namesCount != 0 && filteredCount != 0 else {
            self.BarsSearchNoResultsLabel.isHidden = false
            return 0
        }

        self.BarsSearchNoResultsLabel.isHidden = true
        if tableView == self.tableView {
            return self.names.count
        } else {
            return self.filteredUsers.count
        }
}
```

Comment: Updated question, look i have 7 errors on the same line

Comment: There was a space missing

Comment: the app crashes before it launches. at line :         `guard self.names.count != 0 && self.filteredUsers.count != 0 else {` fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: One or both of your arrays must be an implicitly unwrapped optional - you haven't shown that.  I have updated my code to check for nil or you can initialise an empty array for the implicitly unwrapped optional.  You can see how messy this code is getting and how it is in the wrong place.